# Unable to edit text in react-draft-wysiwyg editor loaded in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using react-draft-wysiwyg.Editor in my React / Redux project with SSR. The Editor use DOM to generate toolbar's dropdowns, so to prevent issue with the SSR, I create the Editor in the componentDidMount. The component is displayed correctly, the content can be selected, but it's impossible to edit any content.

If I don't wait the componentDidMount() and put directly the Editor in the render(), the content is editable, but on direct loading from the SSR, the toolbar's dropdowns are not generated because react-draft-wysiwyg.Editor use the DOM.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form } from 'antd';
import { EditorState, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';
import { stateToHTML } from 'draft-js-export-html';

class Wysiwyg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.html = props.data;

    const contentBlock = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? htmlToDraft(this.html) : null;

    if(contentBlock) {
      const
        contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks),
        editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);

      this.state = {
        editorState: editorState,
        editor: null,
      };
    } else {
      this.state = {
        editorState: null,
        editor: null,
      };
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const
      {
        state,
        onEditorStateChange,
      } = this,
      {
        editorState,
      } = state,
      editor = (
        <Editor
          editorState={editorState}
          onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
        />
      );

    this.setState({
      ...state,
      editor: editor,
    });
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  };

  render() {
    const
      {
        props,
        state,
      } = this,
      {
        form,
        fieldId,
      } = props,
      {
        editorState,
        editor,
      } = state,
      {
        getFieldDecorator,
      } = form;

    const fieldOptions = {
      initialValue: editorState,
    }

    return (
      <Form.Item
        hasFeedback
        label="DESCRIPTION"
      >
        {editor ? getFieldDecorator(fieldId, fieldOptions)(editor) : null}
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }
}

export default Wysiwyg;
```

The Editor content is not editable.

I don't have any error message. I'm clueless....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Editor can't pass through the state. So I set a boolean condition waiting the componentDidMount.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Form } from 'antd';
import { EditorState, ContentState } from 'draft-js';
import { Editor } from 'react-draft-wysiwyg';
import htmlToDraft from 'html-to-draftjs';

class Wysiwyg extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.html = props.data;

    const contentBlock = typeof window !== 'undefined' ? htmlToDraft(this.html) : null;

    if(contentBlock) {
      const
        contentState = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(contentBlock.contentBlocks),
        editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(contentState);

      this.state = {
        editorState: editorState,
        editor: null,
      };
    } else {
      this.state = {
        editorState: null,
        editor: null,
      };
    }

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      editor: true,
    });
  }

  onEditorStateChange = (editorState) => {
    this.setState({
      editorState
    });
  };

  render() {
    const
      {
        props,
        state,
        onEditorStateChange,
      } = this,
      {
        form,
        fieldId,
      } = props,
      {
        editorState,
        editor,
      } = state,
      {
        getFieldDecorator,
      } = form;

    const fieldOptions = {
      initialValue: editorState,
    }

    return (
      <Form.Item
        hasFeedback
        label="DESCRIPTION"
      >
        {editor ? getFieldDecorator(fieldId, fieldOptions)(
          <Editor
            editorState={editorState}
            onEditorStateChange={onEditorStateChange}
          />
        ) : null}
      </Form.Item>
    );
  }
}

export default Wysiwyg;
```

Comment: having same issue in Functional Components with Default Html coming from server. But its not editable.